# When i am trying to run this code i am getting the following error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack, mean

I am trying to connect mongodb database by this code but when running this code I get the error(error at the bottom of the code).
One of the error was in the 7th line where it was resolved by adding 
`{ useNewUrlParser: true }` but still it has more errors. I am using MongoDB version `4.0.1`. Do anybody know how to resolve this error.

```
const express = require('express');     
const mongoose = require('mongoose');  
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');   
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));  
app.set('view engine','ejs');

mongoose.connect('mongod://localhost/students', { useNewUrlParser: true });  
var studentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
    name: String,  
    age:Number,  
    country:String  
});

var Student = mongoose.model("Student", studentSchema);  
var shashank = new Student({  
    name:"Shashank",  
    age:"21",  
    country:"India"  
});    

shashank.save((err,student) => {    
    if(err){     
        console.log('Something went wrong!');     
    }    
    else {      
        console.log("You added: " + student);      
    }      
});      

app.listen(3000,() => {     
    console.log('Server Listening!');     
});
```

Error while running this code!

```
D:\HARDWORK\YelpCamp-Course>node app.js
Server Listening!
                                                                                               (node:14060) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoParseError: Invalid connection string
    at parseConnectionString (D:\HARDWORK\YelpCamp-Course\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\uri_parser.js:216:21)
    at connect (D:\HARDWORK\YelpCamp-Course\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\mongo_client_ops.js:179:3)
    at connectOp (D:\HARDWORK\YelpCamp-Course\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\mongo_client_ops.js:283:3)
    at executeOperation (D:\HARDWORK\YelpCamp-Course\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:420:24)
    at MongoClient.connect (D:\HARDWORK\YelpCamp-Course\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:168:10)
    at Promise (D:\HARDWORK\YelpCamp-Course\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:499:12)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (D:\HARDWORK\YelpCamp-Course\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:496:19)
    at Mongoose.connect (D:\HARDWORK\YelpCamp-Course\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:229:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\HARDWORK\YelpCamp-Course\app.js:9:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
(node:14060) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)                                                                                                                (node:14060) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
mongoose.connect('mongod://localhost/students', { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

It should start with mongodb://..., And  When you use `{ useNewUrlParser: true }` you should always specify the port number in connection string [mongoose reference](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#options) like given below.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/students', { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

here port number `27017` is the default port for MongoDB database.

Comment: Thanks! 
Many errors are gone, but there are few more, please have a look.

`(node:6516) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: #<Object>
(node:6516) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6516) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

Comment: wait lemme take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The host you write is not correct, and it should be. m

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/students', { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

use this two set before connect to moongose more clean and stable for version 5.7

```
mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true);
```

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same issue, I just started the mongo in the terminal by command

1) sudo service mongod start
2) mongo

worked for me.